# How to use the MultipleTextOutputFormat class to rename the default output file to some meaningful names?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

After the reduce phase in Hadoop, I wanted the output file names to be something meaningful depending on the input key value. However I'm not successful on following the example on "Hadoop: The Definative Guide" which used MultipleTextOutputFormat to do this. The reason is that it's based on old API and it doesn't work on the new API ?

Can anybody hint on the solution or point me to the relevant documentation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably right. Most things that worked in the old API don't always work in the new one.

There is a "new way" of doing this now, called [MultipleOutputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/mapreduce/docs/r0.21.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html).